# How to obtain an m*n sub-matrix from a p*q larger matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Came across this while trying to solve a sudoku related question.

I need to return all the 3*3 matrices from the larger 9*9 matrix.

Is there any direct way of doing this in numpy?

My current approach involves performing two splits- first in the horizontal direction and then a vertical split on each element in the list obtained from previous split

```
grid= np.array([[5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2],
     [6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8],
     [1,9,8,3,3,2,5,6,7],
     [8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3],
     [4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1],
     [7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6],
     [9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4],
     [2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5],
     [3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9]])


for i in np.split(grid,3):
    for t in (np.hsplit(i,3)):
        print(t)
```

Comment: Do you mean all **non-overlapping** 3x3 matrices, i.e. a total of 9 matrices?

Comment: Can you explain your current approach in code?

Comment: @kazemakase : added

Comment: @ eozd - yes , like the 9 sub matrices of a sudoku from the larger 9*9 grid

Answer (score 0):

You can achive tiling by adjusting shape and strides of the array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(81).reshape(9, 9)

r = x.strides[0]
c = x.strides[1]

y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(3, 3, 3, 3), strides=(r*3, c*3, r, c))
print(y[1, 1])
# [[30 31 32]
#  [39 40 41]
#  [48 49 50]]
```

1. With `shape=(3,3, 3,3)` we specify the desired shape of the output: 3x3 sub arrays of size 3x3 each.
2. With `strides=` we specify how the memory address changes when going from one element to the next along a dimension. `r*3, c*3`: the subgrids are spaced in steps of three rows and columns. `r, c`: the spacing between elements in the subgrid is the same as in the original array.

If you want a simple list of subarrays instead of a 2D arangement, you can do `y.reshape(9, 3, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the shortest path, but you can get the result with several reshapes and transposes:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(81).reshape((9, 9))
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
#  [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
#  [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26]
#  [27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35]
#  [36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44]
#  [45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53]
#  [54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62]
#  [63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71]
#  [72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80]]
b = np.transpose(np.transpose(np.transpose(a.reshape((3, 3, 9)), (1, 0, 2)).reshape((3, -1))).reshape((9, 3, 3)), (0, 2, 1))
print(b[0])
# [[ 0  1  2]
#  [ 9 10 11]
#  [18 19 20]]
print(b[1])
# [[ 3  4  5]
#  [12 13 14]
#  [21 22 23]]
# ...
```